# Looping results to insert new div with complexities

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

How can I loop results to insert new div with complexities for each result?

I have the following database table with following columns:

```
ID | UserID | Title | Introduction | Content | Images | Background | Date | Pinned
```

I have the following PHP code:

```
if($latest = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Pinned='0' LIMIT 4")) {
    if($latest->num_rows > 0) {
                                            //<-- result loop here 
    } else {
        echo '<h1 class="alert fade">No Posts</h1>';
    }

    $latest->close();
};
```

I would like to format the output as follows:

```
<div class="post standard" style="background-image:url([1]);">
    <a href="view.php?id=[2]">
        <div class="shader"></div>
            <div class="info">
                <h1>[3]</h1>
                <p>[4] - [5]</p>
            </div>
</div>

[1] - Background
[2] - ID
[3] - Title
[4] - UserID
[5] - Date
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which should do what you need. I used just one `echo`, you can split it into more `echo`es, or go out of PHP block. Doesn't matter.

```
<?php

if ($latest->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $latest->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '
            <div class="post standard" style="background-image:url(' . $row['background'] . ');">
                <a href="view.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">
                    <div class="shader"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                    <h1>' . $row['title'] . '</h1>
                    <p>' . $row['userID'] . ' - ' . $row['date'] . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        ';
    }
}

?>
```

Example with putting HTML code outside PHP block.

```
<?php

if ($latest->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $latest->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
        <div class="post standard" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $row['background']; ?>');">
            <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                <div class="shader"></div>
                <div class="info">
                <h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $row['userID']; ?> - <?php echo $row['date']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I do is the following 
let's say that we're inside the loop for example

```
if($latest = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Pinned='0' LIMIT 4")) {
if($latest->num_rows > 0) {
                                        //<-- result loop here 
// end the php tag here 
?>
<div></div> 
<!-- you html tags here-->
<?php // reopen your php tag here again 


} else {
    echo '<h1 class="alert fade">No Posts</h1>';
}

$latest->close();
```

};